# Sitecore save with silent and search

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I am making use of the silent feature to stop other save events from triggering e.g.

```
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item.Fields["aField"].Value = "123";
item.Editing.EndEdit(true,true);
```

If you query this 'item' for the "aField" directly after saving, you are unable to view the change straight away. I believe by specifying the silent parameter in EndEdit, this stops the item from being put in the Event queue.

I am assuming when an item is put into the event queue - it is indexed straight away and therefore searchable.

Can someone confirm if this is the correct behavior and secondly - how to add the item to the index without re-indexing the whole database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats correct, If you pass silent as true, it will temporarily disable events. So, 'item save' event will not be logged in EventQueue, which means it will not be indexed.

To reindex item programmatically, use this code:

```
var tempItem = (SitecoreIndexableItem)item;
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("Index Name").Refresh(tempItem);
```

Comment: I believe the above would work - In the end I had to reindex a lot of data so I went down the rebuild route using:

ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("Index Name").Rebuild();